# vue.js 3 typescript vue-chartjs Radar data not reactive

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vue-chartjs

I have a problem with vue 3 vue-chartjs not updating the data when I add a new dataset. Basically the data is not reactive. If I add a new hardcoded object with datasets it works, but not when its added using array push. I tried anything I could think of including recreating the object using a labels array and a dataset array that I add in a new var object.

Thank you for your time,
ukw

```
<template>
     <Radar id="my-chart-id-1" :options="BarChartOptions" :data="BarData" />

     <button type="button" @click="addNewData">Add</button>
</template>

<script lang="ts">
import { mapActions } from "pinia";
import { defineComponent } from 'vue'
import { Radar } from 'vue-chartjs'
import { Chart as ChartJS, Title, Tooltip, Legend, BarElement, CategoryScale, LinearScale, RadialLinearScale, PointElement, LineElement, Filler } from 'chart.js'

ChartJS.register(Title, Tooltip, Legend, BarElement, CategoryScale, LinearScale, RadialLinearScale, PointElement, LineElement, Filler)

export default defineComponent({
    setup() {

    },
    components: {
        Radar,
    },
    data() {
        return {
            BarChartOptions: {
                scale: {
                    min: 0,
                    max: 100,
                },
                responsive: true,
                elements: {
                    line: {
                        borderWidth: 1
                    }
                },
                scales: {
                    r: {
                        grid: {
                            color: '#CCCCCC'
                        },
                    }
                }
            },
            BarData: {
                labels: [
                    '1. Title',
                    '2. Title',
                    '3. Title',
                    '4. Title',
                    '5. Title',
                ],
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'First',
                    data: [10, 30, 30, 30, 30],
                    fill: true,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 99, 132, 0.2)',
                    borderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                    pointBackgroundColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)',
                    pointBorderColor: '#fff',
                    pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
                    pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)'
                }
                ]
            },
},
methods: {
        addNewData() {
               let obj = {
                    label: 'test',
                    data: [50, 50, 50, 50, 50],
                    fill: true,
                    backgroundColor: 'rgba(155, 99, 132, 0.5)',
                    borderColor: 'rgb(155, 99, 132)',
                    pointBackgroundColor: 'rgb(155, 99, 132)',
                    pointBorderColor: '#fff',
                    pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
                    pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)'
                }
                this.BarData.datasets.push(obj);
        }
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

vue-charts don't seem to be deeply reactive.  Changes to nested properties such as `datasets` won't trigger updates like you'd expect.  Reassigning the entire data object is a possible workaround.

```js
addNewData() {
  const obj = {
    label: 'test',
    data: [50, 50, 50, 50, 50],
    fill: true,
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(155, 99, 132, 0.5)',
    borderColor: 'rgb(155, 99, 132)',
    pointBackgroundColor: 'rgb(155, 99, 132)',
    pointBorderColor: '#fff',
    pointHoverBackgroundColor: '#fff',
    pointHoverBorderColor: 'rgb(255, 99, 132)'
  }
  // re-assign entire object to trigger reactivity
  this.BarData = {
    ...this.BarData,
    datasets: [...this.BarData.datasets, obj]
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, this is the way. Thank you so much for your help!