# Can a Qausar slider value control a vue-chartjs chart? (Vue3, Quasar, Chartjs)

Tags: vuejs3, quasar-framework, quasar, vue-chartjs

I'm building a budget app with quasar.
I'm trying to update the bar value of a chartjs BarChart with a q-slider.
But the bar isn't updating when I submit the value. The 'income.value' gives me the correct value in the console. The income.value has the be in an array because the barchart needs te receive more values.

```
<template>
  <div class="q-pa-md">
    <q-form @submit="onSubmit" class="q-gutter-md">
      <div class="q-mt-xl">
        <q-slider
          name="income"
          v-model="income"
          label-always
          :min="0"
          :max="10000"
          :step="10"
        />
      </div>

      <div>
        <q-btn label="Submit" type="submit" color="primary" />
      </div>
    </q-form>

    <Bar id="my-chart-id" :options="chartOptions" :data="chartData" />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { Bar } from 'vue-chartjs';
import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
  BarElement,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
} from 'chart.js';
import { ref } from 'vue';

ChartJS.register(
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
  BarElement,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale
);

const income = ref(0);

export default {
  name: 'BarChart',
  components: { Bar },
  setup() {
    const chartData = ref({
      labels: ['January'],
      datasets: [{ data: [income.value] }],
    });

    const chartOptions = ref({
      responsive: true,
      scales: {
        y: {
          beginAtZero: true,
          max: 10000,
        },
      },
    });

    const onSubmit = () => {
      console.log('Submitted Income Value:', income.value);
      chartData.value.datasets[0].data = [income.value];
      this.$data._chart.update();
    };

    return { income, chartData, chartOptions, onSubmit };
  },
};
</script>
```

I'm trying to push the income.value to the dataset data array.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vue.js 3 typescript vue-chartjs Radar data not reactive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77290444/vue-js-3-typescript-vue-chartjs-radar-data-not-reactive)

Comment: Yes it does! Thanks for pointing it out for me!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the help of Yoduh, I found an answer for this, more like a short workaround. You need to reassign the entire dataset to update the chart after changes.

````
   const updateChart = () => {
      const newData = {
        labels: ['Income', 'Expenditure', 'Savings'],
        datasets: [{ data: [income.value, 1500, 250] }],
      };

      chartData.value = {
        ...chartData.value,
        ...newData,
      };
    };
    ```
````